# Custom deserialization for some class?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am working on a project that has some very complex configuration files in JSON. An example of such is this (Just a property in a larger cog)

```
"Visuals": {
  "UseAnimation": [
    {
      "Name": "idle",
      "RunConditions": {
        "cur_processed_inv": "IsZero"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "running",
      "RunConditions": {
        "cur_processed_inv": "IsGreaterThanZero"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The project has decided to use Newtonsoft.Json to do the conversion. The way that this is currently structured is a series of classes. In this instance, `Visuals` and `UseAnimation` are classes. `RunConditions` is managed by a class called Conditions, which currently looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Conditions
{
    public List<ParameterCondition> ParamConditions { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that the json data doesn't match the class structure. The reasons for this are complex, but the short version is the code used to be XML based, and it seems this bit was never properly tested when converted to JSON. If possible, I don't want to alter the data files, nor the structure in which the data will ultimately be saved. The ideal solution would be to make some code that can custom parse just this class, which is called by the JSON Deserialization code that is being run, something like this:

```
public static Conditions Deserialize(JToken jtoken)
{
    Conditions condition = new Conditions();
    condition.ParamConditions = new List<ParameterCondition>();
    foreach (JProperty prop in jtoken)
    {
        ConditionType type = (ConditionType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConditionType), prop.Value.ToString(), true);
        condition.ParamConditions.Add(new ParameterCondition()
        {
            Condition = type,
            ParameterName = prop.Name
        });
    }

    return condition;
}
```

In looking around, I have seen solutions where you can completely customly deserialize everything, but I just want this one piece to be deserialized.

This is for the open source game known as [Project Porcuipine](https://github.com/OrderOfThePorcupine/ProjectPorcupine). Some bits that might help:

- [The full .json files](https://github.com/OrderOfThePorcupine/ProjectPorcupine/blob/master/Assets/StreamingAssets/Data/Prototypes/Furniture.json)
- [The full .cs code referenced](https://github.com/OrderOfThePorcupine/ProjectPorcupine/tree/master/Assets/Scripts/Models/Buildable/Components)

Comment: If you are already using Newtonsoft.Json, then you can write a custom JsonConverter/JsonConverter<T> for your `Conditions` type (and perhaps further custom JsonConverter's for other types of yours, if necessary). Look around here on StackOverflow, the Newtonsoft.Json documentation and the interwebs; there is plenty written about JsonConverter's that you can take advantage of and learn from...

Comment: From what I've been able to tell, that works well enough if you are trying to just deserialize the conditions. I haven't been able to find an example on how to just deserialize a part of a JSON structure using JsonConverter, although maybe I'm just missing how to make that work.

Comment: Use a separate class that represents the output structure you want and see realize that instead

Comment: Okay, I think I found the one missing piece, and now it seems to be working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Write a class to parse this, extending JsonConverter.

```
public class ConditionsJsonConvertor : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Conditions);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Conditions condition = new Conditions();
        condition.ParamConditions = new List<ParameterCondition>();
        JToken jtoken = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        foreach (JProperty prop in jtoken)
        {
            ConditionType type = (ConditionType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConditionType), prop.Value.ToString(), true);
            condition.ParamConditions.Add(new ParameterCondition()
            {
                Condition = type,
                ParameterName = prop.Name
            });
        }

        return condition;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Conditions conditions = (Conditions)value;
        JObject jObjs = new JObject();
        foreach (ParameterCondition pCondition in conditions.ParamConditions)
        {
            JProperty prop = new JProperty(pCondition.ParameterName, pCondition.Condition.ToString());
            jObjs.Add(prop);
        }
        jObjs.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

Step 2: In code, when referencing parsing Conditions, let it know which JsonConverter to use.

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ConditionsJsonConvertor))]
    public Conditions RunConditions { get; set; }
```